Using SwiftData and getting a Nil value for a very odd reason which I can't understand why
I am trying to learn SwiftData, so I created a very simple app (macOS) to learn the basics.  I ran into what turns out to be very odd behavior (at least I am not understanding).
In my code below, everything works as expected - Until I comment out the "if" around my Button in ContentView (Look for my <----- in the code) I get the following problem - I run the app and add 1 'Note' to it.  Quit the app, and then go back into it and click on the Note I added before - it comes up as Nil, even though I know it is not (the print stmt prints out the UUID).
Put the "if" stmt back in and rerun - it works as expected.
What is happening when the Button view is always there (no if stmt) ?
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct SwiftDataTryApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Note.self)
    }
}

@Model
class Note: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var titleText: String = ""
    var bodyText: String = ""
    init() {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var notes: [Note]
    @State var showEditNoteView: Bool = false
    @State var selectedNote: Note?
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            List {
                ForEach(notes) { note in
                    Text(note.titleText)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if !showEditNoteView {
                                print(note.id)
                                selectedNote = note
                                showEditNoteView = true
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            if !showEditNoteView {  //    <------- Without this, I see the problem
                Button("+") {
                    selectedNote = Note()
                    modelContext.insert(selectedNote!)
                    showEditNoteView = true
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .popover(isPresented: $showEditNoteView) {
            if selectedNote != nil { EditNoteView(isPresented: $showEditNoteView, note: selectedNote!) }
            else { Text("selectedNote is nil") .padding() }
        }
    }
}

struct EditNoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Bindable var note: Note
    @State var titleText: String = ""
    @State var bodyText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Title", text: $titleText)
            TextEditor(text: $bodyText)
            Button("Save") { isPresented = false }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 728, height: 512)
        .onAppear {
            titleText = note.titleText
            bodyText = note.bodyText
        }
        .onDisappear {
            note.titleText = titleText
            note.bodyText = bodyText
            do {
                try modelContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}


To add to the mystery, if you comment out the if stmt to 'create' the problem... then do the following:  add a second Note. Quit the app and run it again.  Click either one of the 2 Notes and you get the Nil... then click the other Note and it works... again click the 1st note you clicked and it works now too.

Try this approach using a .popover(item: $selectedNote)... to
pass the note to be edited, without the showEditNoteView. And dismiss() to dismiss the popover.
@Model
class Note: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var titleText: String
    var bodyText: String
    
    init(titleText: String, bodyText: String) {  // <--- here
        self.titleText = titleText
        self.bodyText = bodyText
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var notes: [Note]

    @State private var selectedNote: Note?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            List {
                ForEach(notes) { note in
                    Text(note.titleText)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedNote = note  // <--- here
                        }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems) // <-- for testing
            }
            .padding()
            Button("+") {
                let addNote = Note(titleText: "new note", bodyText: "new body")  // <--- here
                modelContext.insert(addNote)
                selectedNote = addNote
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .popover(item: $selectedNote) { selection in  // <--- here
            EditNoteView(note: selection)
        }
    }
    
    // for testing
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(notes[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditNoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // <--- here

    var note: Note   // <--- here
    
    @State private var titleText: String = ""
    @State private var bodyText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $titleText).border(.red)
            TextEditor(text: $bodyText).border(.red)
            Button("Save") { dismiss() }  // <--- here
        }
        .padding(10)
        .frame(width: 728, height: 512)
        .onAppear {
            titleText = note.titleText
            bodyText = note.bodyText
        }
        .onDisappear {
            note.titleText = titleText
            note.bodyText = bodyText
            do {
                try modelContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

Alternatively, you could use @Bindable var note: Note, such as:
struct EditNoteView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // <--- here

    @Bindable var note: Note   // <--- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $note.titleText).border(.red)  // <--- here
            TextEditor(text: $note.bodyText).border(.red)
            Button("Save") { dismiss() }  // <--- here
        }
        .padding(10)
        .frame(width: 728, height: 512)
        .onDisappear {
            do {
                try modelContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the help... while trying to get this to work, I found some other 'problems' with the way I was approaching using SwiftData - so I rethought my approach and started from scratch.
